# Failed To Set Up SDK Google APIs 11 not found

Tags: android, api, android-studio, sdk

I've just installed Android Studio 2.1.2 on both my Windows 7 PC and also my Mac. I get the same error on both machines. I've not previous installed it on my Mac.

The full error is:

```
Failed to Set Up SDK
Error:Module'app': platform 'Google Inc.: APIs 11' not found
```

I've spent a day on this.  None of the answers previous given have worked. I cannot find the `AndroidStudioPreview` folder that has been suggested as the problem on previous answers, so that approach may be out of date, but I may be wrong.

The relevant APIs are definitely installed on both machines and I've also installed Android Support Repository.  There is only one SDK library on the Mac for sure.

I'd be grateful for any ideas to resolve this issue, please.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the SDK installed?

I am assuming some elevated permissions were used during installation. The SDK may be in a path that the OS protects C:\windows and C:\Programs are difficult to r/w to unless you have elevated permissions.

When I installed a much earlier version of Android Studio, the original location of the android SDK was in the Programs folder which a 'user' has very little permissions. Running as the Administrator allowed me to delete the SDK. As just my 'user' account I reinstalled in my Windows 10 'User/Home' folder where I have the proper r/w, delete, etc. permissions. The %APPDATA% or the mac equivalent might be even better.

I plan to install the SDK on a flash drive some day since I believe anybody who logs on locally can r/w etc unless someone alters the permissions.